# how to draw sequence diagram from java code

Tags: java, uml, sequence, diagram

currently I am drawing sequence diagram from java code, I know there are several shortcut extension software exist, still, I want to draw it by my hand and to figure out what is going on.

I am working with these piece of code from java:

```
import java.util.List;

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student student = new Student(2);

        student.addClass(new Class("SE 450"));

        student.addClass(new Class("SE 550"));

        System.out.println(student.getFormattedSchedule());
}

class Student {

        //instance field;

        private final List<Class> classes;

        private final int maxNumberOfClasses;

        //constructor

        Student(int maxNumberOfClasses){

                classes = new ArrayList();

                this.maxNumberOfClasses = maxNumberOfClasses;

        }

        //Mutator Method     

        void addClass(Class newClass){

                if(classes.size() < maxNumberOfClasses)

                        classes.add(newClass);
        }


        List<Class> getClasses(){

                return classes;         

        }

        String getFormattedSchedule(){

                if(classes.size() == 0)

                        return "No classes added.";


                String schedule = "";

                for (Class studentClass : classes) {

                        schedule += studentClass.getName() + "\r\n";

                }

                return schedule;
```

and what I draw from this code something like that:

[image]

In this case, I do not know how to continue to draw the diagram because i do not know how draw the diagram for this piece of code:

classes.add(newClass);

Does anyone have idea about that? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could treat `classes` as an own lifeline and send the `add` message to it. But that just looks like overkill. Either

- you model it sort of a self-message (accompanied by a note) or
- you just use a note at the location
- or (what I suggest) you don't go into that detail.

An SD is no visual programming aid. It shall give an overview of complex procedures so one get's an idea of what's going on. Reduce to the max.

Comment: So in other words, it is not necessary to draw the diagram for "classes.add(newClass)" ?  What if I ignore that, what is the next step to draw the diagram?  Is that to draw the digram from "String getFormattedSchedule()"? I am sooooo appreciate that you help !

Comment: I can't give you the "solution" for the above. The idea is, not to document each bit but to abstract the whole thing so one has an idea how the schedule works.

Comment: Consider extending the `opt` to just return the "no classes" in one partition and just a self-call describing that a class has been added in the other.

Comment: thank you for your help! I think you have already explained it more than I expected :)